# ASP. NET - SqlDataSource update data base

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I'm learning ASP and I get stuck to update the database using asp SqlDataSource and GridView.
I have the following controls:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BPersonalConnectionString %>" 
        OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
        ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Marca], [Nume], [Prenume], [Salariu], [Profesia] FROM [Salariati]"
        UpdateCommand="update [Salariati] set [Marca] = Marca, [Nume] = Nume, [Prenume] = Prenume, [Salariu] = Salariu, [Profesia] = Profesia
                       where [Marca] = @original_Marca">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Marca" Type="Int16"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Nume" Type="String" Size="20"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Prenume" Type="String" Size="20" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Salariu" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Profesia" Type="String" Size="10" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_Marca" Type="Int16" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" 
        runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
        DataKeyNames="Marca"
        AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="3"></asp:GridView>
```

Whenever I try to edit and update a item I dont get any result. The grid shows me exact same values as before the update. I did not wrote any code in code behind file. 
I looked to some other examples already done on this subject but I was unable to identify the cause of the update problem.
Any hints?
Thanks!!!

Comment: you are missing the `@` parameter symbol in your Update statement here is a msdn reference to look at [SqlDataSource.UpdateParameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updateparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) use google if you need more examples

Comment: if I put @ then I get the error: "Must declare scalar variable: @Marca"...

Comment: Either switch to ControlParameters or set them in the code behind.

Comment: why don't you create a method that updates the database using a different approach in code behind personally using UpdateParameters is rather outdated in my opinion

Comment: After some tries I found what was wrong in the code above. First, as Marca is PK should not be used it the update command before the WHERE clause. Also I deleted UpdateParameters section too. And I added @ for each value to set. Which means that a pair Field=Value is now Field=@Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this by creating a method that returns a DataSet as well as passing parameters to execute the query then do something like this I will post the same thing returning a DataTable as well but it's pretty straight forward it works with any query that you pass dynamically

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return ds;
    }
}
```

> if you want to return a DataTable

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataSet(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConn"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        try
        {
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code Behind to fill gridView, it's much easier and offer you more handling and customization to gridView binding

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113278/populate-a-datagridview-with-sql-query-results) you will find some guide for the simplest way to connect gridView with sql data source.

Answer (score 0):

You added parameters, but where is the value?

And look to your query: to some parameters you didn't used `@`, but for last one used. Change your query to the following:

```
UpdateCommand="update [Salariati] set [Marca] = @Marca, [Nume] = @Nume, [Prenume] = @Prenume, [Salariu] = @Salariu, [Profesia] = @Profesia
                   where [Marca] = @original_Marca">
```

And then your parameters:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourControlID" Name="Marca" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourControlID" Name="Nume" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourControlID" Name="Prenume" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourControlID" Name="Salariu" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourControlID" Name="Profesia" PropertyName="Text" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="YourControlID" Name="original_Marca" PropertyName="Text" />
```